# Send pushwoosh notification from Symfony web app

Tags: cordova, symfony, notifications, pushwoosh

Hi every one Im working on a project using symfony2, which must send to mobile app user some notification after some event, the mobile app is created by my collegue, and when he test the notification from pushwoosh website, the device on which the app is installed receives notification, but when I try to send a notification using the pushwoosh api from symfony it gives me an error : "  Status code : 210 Status message : Account not found " and my config file is like this :

```
prezent_pushwoosh:
    application_id: XXXXX-XXXXX
    api_key: qsdfqsdfqsdfsdfsdfsdf_qsqsdfqsdfqsdf
    client_class: Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Client\Pushwoosh
```

NOTE :We have a FREE ACOUNT and I set the application_id and the api_key correctly,!
plz I need help, Its the first time that I work with the notification pushwoosh

Comment: api_key looks like wrong, because it can't contains underscore character and must be 64 characters long. You may find it on https://cp.pushwoosh.com/api_access page. I think you use this library https://github.com/Prezent/pushwoosh-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md

Comment: thanks for responding, I have another question, is it free to access the api from a web app, to send notifications from my web app??